# Complete list of Google Pub/Sub pre-defined topics?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I used Google Pub/Sub to receive status changes on a build workflow I have in Google Build.  There's a pre-defined topic called `cloud-builds` where you just name a new topic `cloud-builds` and Cloud Builds updates will populate the topic.

> The Pub/Sub topic to which Cloud Build publishes these build update messages is called cloud-builds.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications

I'm curious if there is a complete list of pre-defined topics for Pub/Sub that automatically pipe from different services.

I looked around the docs for Pub/Sub but couldn't find a complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's no list of topics like this. There are some other services that offer Pub/Sub notifications, for example [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications), but there's no centralized place where they are all documented. You will need to refer to the documentation of the particular service you are interested in.